# Installing "eXo platform" social collaboration

Tags: software-installation

I cannot seem to find how to install the latest "exo platform" social collaboration package in ubuntu lts 14.04. (64 bits)
Downloaded the latest release from the official website.

I'd love to have a tutorial step by step. If you can provide info about the issue, it'd be very helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way for trying eXo platform is 30 days trial [eXo Platform Ubuntu VM](https://community.exoplatform.com/portal/intranet/downloads) (Registration needed). eXo provides a fully working image.

There is official installation instruction:
https://www.exoplatform.com/docs/public/index.jsp?topic=%2FPLF43%2FPLFAdminGuide.InstallationAndStartup.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer! i am going to try that out. will be back if any issue arises.